# Does Google reindex page before expiration?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search

I have a Classifieds website, where users can add new Ads. The ads are actual for 90 days, after that they are available for another 100 days, but users can't see the owners number. After that they are deleted from the system. I have set the last day of the Ad to be its expiration date.

The problem is, that users sometimes renew their ads (if they have not sold their items) and the expiration date changes. But Google does not know about that if it does not recrawl. So I wanted to ask - will Google recrawl the ad in it last date before expiration, or any suggestions of what I should do to ensure that all search links are not deleted for Actual Ads. ?

Comment: "But Google does not know about that if it does not recrawl." - How is Google aware of the "expiration date" to begin with?

Comment: @w3dk from Googles documentation - they have a special meta tag for instance <META NAME="GOOGLEBOT" CONTENT="unavailable_after: 2017-08-08 15:40:39 EST">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google will re-crawl those pages when it sees fit.... if Google and other search engines determine the page as low quality or has copy and pasted duplicate content then the re-crawling of those pages will be longer, users that update their pages regularly will naturally receive a higher re-crawl rate than other pages that do not get updated regularly.

There is no 'natural' way to prompt Google to automatically re-crawl a page and the 'spent' time on your site recrawling is down to site authority. Sites that offer 'GREAT' unique content get higher allocated resources.

Comment: Will it help me, if I add a sitemap and will google understand that links outside of the sitemap are not worth crawling?

Comment: Google uses sitemap to discover uncrawlable content. If you want to prevent Google indexing some pages then use robots.txt with noindex